# Colouring a subset of data in Lattice plots R

Tags: r, lattice

I have plotted a `xyplot` in `lattice` of shellfish catch rates by year grouped by survey area using the below code:

```
xyplot(catch.rate ~ Year | Area, data, xlab = "Year", ylab = "Catch rate",
    col ="black", par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col="white")))
```

I have one year of data that I would like to highlight on the plot in a different colour (e.g. red). I created a subset of this data with:

```
subset <- grep("^0214A",data$Haul_ID,ignore.case=TRUE)
```

I have done something similar with the standard R plots using `points` before but as I am new to `lattice` and I am not sure how to do this using this package.

Comment: Please, could you add an example of the plot you would like to obtain. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For plots without conditioning variables, the `col=` argument accepts a vector parallel to the points being plotted, so for instance

```
xyplot(mpg~disp, mtcars, col=mtcars$cyl, pch=20, cex=4)
```

colors points by the  number of cylinders. Maybe you'd do

```
cols=c("red", "green")[grepl("^0214A", data$Haul_ID, ignore.case=TRUE) + 1L]
```

For plots with conditioning variables, one can write a panel function that accepts the `col` vector and `subscripts`, an index into the data describing the rows currently being plotted. Pass the arguments to the panel function to `panel.xyplot()`, adjusting the color of each point to reflect the subset of data in the panel. Here's the panel function

```
panel <- function(..., col, subscripts) {
    panel.xyplot(..., col=col[subscripts])
}
```

and in action

```
xyplot(mpg ~ disp | factor(cyl), mtcars, col=mtcars$cyl, 
       panel=panel, pch=20, cex=4)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Unfortunately when I run the cols line above then use col = cols in my plot it doesn't highlight the correct points representing 0214A. I have tried some ifelse lines but this doesn't seem to be working either.